# How can i remove the circle drawn in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, drawable, geometry, quartz-core

I have this code where I draw circles on the screen, and I want to remove just the last circle drawn. What can I do? The code is set to draw a circle when I tap twice. I want to remove the last circle drawn when I tap one time.

```
- (UIBezierPath *)makeCircleAtLocation:(CGPoint)location radius:(CGFloat)radius {

    iOSCircle *circle = [[iOSCircle alloc] init];
    circle.circleCenter = location;
    circle.circleRadius = radius;
    [totalCircles addObject:circle];

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path addArcWithCenter:circle.circleCenter
                radius:circle.circleRadius
                startAngle:0.0
                endAngle:M_PI * 2.0
               clockwise:YES];

    return path;
}

- (IBAction) tapEvent: (UIGestureRecognizer *) sender
{

    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = [[self makeCircleAtLocation:location radius:2.5] CGPath];
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    //shapeLayer.fillColor = nil;
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.5;

    // Add CAShapeLayer to our view

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];

    // Save this shape layer in a class property for future reference,
    // namely so we can remove it later if we tap elsewhere on the screen.

    self.circleLayer = shapeLayer;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your circle in a distinct `CAShapeLayer` layer using a CGPath, and add it as a sublayer of your view.layer.  That way, you will have total control over that circle (showing or hiding it).